# Trying to assign a bounty with an unregistered account, during the grace period, causes a silent error

Tags: bug, status-completed, bounties, unregistered-users

Assigning a bounty from an unregistered account silently fails. The notice about the bounty says, "you have 23 hours to award the bounty"; selecting one of the answers shows a browser dialog box, and then (once "OK" is selected in that dialog box) an alert box. It is the same alert box used to say, e.g., the number of close votes still required.

There isn't any message error; the text is just, "(click on this box to dismiss)."

This happens in [Unable to add JavaScript on a page](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/34071/unable-to-add-javascript-on-a-page), and [What is the basic concept behind hooks?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/26290/what-is-basic-concept-behind-hooks)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your friend probably shouldn't have been able to offer bounties in the first place without registering his account. It kinda looks like the check for that is... Half-way there.

Since it was *the wrong half*, I've refunded both of those bounties. For now, advice him to register and re-offer them; naturally, this will have to be fixed in the future.

Answer (score 5):

This will be fixed in the next build. As Shog said, unregistered users should not be able to start bounties in the first place.

This is in part to prevent fraud and in part to prevent the near-inevitable pain when someone offers a bounty from an unregistered profile and then loses access to said profile.

Cookie-based accounts + rep transfer? Not even once.